# how to do a graceful uwsgi reload via bash script?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have a django application which is executing a bash script.
I require the nginx server to restart so I run `/etc/init.d/nginx reload` which works great. I have been using `restart uwsgi` for uwsgi but I need to do a **graceful reload** instead of a hard server restart.

How can I do this?

---

I am currently running a bash `reload uwsgi` function through `subprocess.popen`. It seems to be only reloading the process that is calling the subprocess not all sites being hosted by the uwsgi instance. `importing uwsgi` and running `uwsgi.reload` seems to also only effect the calling process. Is there a switch for either uwsgi through python or bash that allows restarting all uwsgi proces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in python

```
import uwsgi
uwsgi.reload()
```

Comment: the uwsgi.reload() is working intermittently. it seems to be restarting the server before some of my processes are finished. i'm running this through a django application and want it to restart the entire server.

Answer (score 19):

**SIGHUP**

You can restart uWSGI by sending the SIGHUP signal to your uWSGI process like so:

```
kill -HUP <process-id>
```

If you want to automate this in a bash script, you can have uWSGI write away it's process id by supplying the `pidfile` option, for example like:

```
--pidfile=/tmp/uwsgi.pid
```

Then you can reload the process by:

```
uwsgi --reload /tmp/uwsgi.pid
```

**touch-reload**

You can also start uWSGI with the `touch-reload` argument, which specifies a file that when touched makes uWSGI reload:

```
--touch-reload=/some/file
```

Then uWSGI will reload when you touch the file:

```
touch /some/file
```

Remember that you can only reload uWSGI when it's running with the master process mode, but that's usually the case though.

More information:
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#reloading-the-server